# How to display admin panel in frontend for non-admin users

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I had been using a plugin called **"Easy Author Image"** to display and upload images as profile picture. This plugin actually triggers the **"meta-upload.php"** file in **"wp-admin"**. When I log-in as admin in my frontend and upload a file, it works perfectly fine but when I tried using a non-admin role it didn't allow me to access the upload page. I tried the following code but still it didn't work.

```
function allow_nonadmin_uploads() {
        if ( current_user_can('contributor') && !current_user_can('upload_files') ){
        $jobseeker = get_role('contributor');
        $jobseeker->add_cap('upload_files');
        }
}

add_action('admin_init', 'allow_nonadmin_uploads'); 
add_action('init', 'allow_nonadmin_uploads');
```

Comment: `'contributor'` is not a valid [Capability Parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Capabilities_Parameters) for [current_user_can()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Capabilities_Parameters).

Comment: So if I put **!current_user_can('upload_files')** alone in the condition would be enough?

Comment: No, you should have a look at the [roles and capabilities of Contributors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor). They can `delete_posts`, `edit_posts`, and `read`. Contributors actually can't even upload files (that's reserved for [Authors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Author)).

Comment: But this part of the code **$jobseeker->add_cap('upload_files');** will add such capability right?

Comment: Yep, should work. So I suppose I'd change your conditional to something like `if ( current_user_can('edit_posts') && !current_user_can('upload_files') ) {`. That'll check if they're at least a contributor (because they can `edit_posts`).

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting this msg on the frontend :(


**Access Denied.

Your site administrator has blocked your access to the WordPress back-office.**